# VS 2012RC Entity Framework Model First still generates ObjectContext based code

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I used EF (Model First) today for the first time since installing VS2012RC. I was surprised to see that the generated code inherited from ObjectContext (EF 4.x style) rather than DbContext (EF 5.x). To make sure that I hadn't missed something obvious I found and followed the following tutorial - [MSDN Model First Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj205424)

with the same result. At ~4:10 in the video it clearly shows that BloggingContext inherits DbContext. My generated code:

```
/// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
public partial class BloggingContext : ObjectContext
{
```

My .edmx file is in the root project folder and no template files (*.tt) get added automatically as the video shows they should. If I manually 'Add Code Generation Item' (DbContext Fluent...) the code does get generated properly.

Is this a known problem with the RC version of VS or any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the transition to DbContext happened post RC. The tutorials/walkthrough for EF5 are (at least should be) using VS 2012 RTM and this is the reason why you see DbContext. Since VS 2012 RTM shipped in August you should no longer be using the RC version but RTM.

Comment: Thanks for that. Thought I was going bonkers for a while there. :)